# Inception situation with oracle (sub query stuffs)

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, subquery

For Oracle,
From these tables,

**Table 1 `CUSTOMER : has cust_fname, cust_lname, cust_id`**

**Table 2 `SALESORDER : has so_number, so_custid`**

**Table 3 `ITEM : has item_qty, item_sonum`**

**`while CUST_ID = SO_CUSTID and SO_NUMBER = ITEM_SONUM (FK relationship)`**

I want to show customer name with full name (means cust_fname+cust_lname) whereas this customer (just one) is the one who had ordered the highest numbers of items (means has to do something with item_qty).

How can I write a code for this task?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select cust_fname, cust_lname
from
(select c.cust_fname, c.cust_lname
from customer c join salesorder so on so.so_custid = c.cust_id
join ITEM i on i.item_sonum = so.so_number
group by c.cust_fname, cust_lname
order by sum(i.item_qty) desc)
where rownum = 1
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/552ba/1)

```
select cust_fname, cust_lname
from
(select c.cust_fname, c.cust_lname, rank() over (order by sum(i.item_qty) desc) rnk
from customer c join salesorder so on so.so_custid = c.cust_id
join ITEM i on i.item_sonum = so.so_number
group by c.cust_fname, cust_lname
)
where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much again A.B.Cade. Your answer is so genius likes you're sitting next to me even you didn't see any data. I will change my religious status into you now. Thank you

Comment: excuse me A.B.Cade, but where can I add rank function over here. It keeps error. Should I use rank() with over() function?

Comment: @NiickMosqow, this is pretty much like your other question... There is a nice post [here](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) which I think you need to read...