# sql statement finding total of an amount

Tags: sql, oracle, database

I am trying to write an SQL statement that can find a company's top client. A top client is defined as one that has purchased the most (total purchase amount) among all the company's clients, not just a the max amount in 1 purchase. How would I go at solving this one? I don't have much experience with SQL but what I do have so far is:

```
SELECT CLIENT.CLIENTNO, CLIENT.CLIENT NAME, PURCHASE.AMOUNT
FROM PURCHASE, CLIENT
WHERE PURCHASE.CLIENTNO = CLIENT.CLIENTNO
GROUP BY CLIENT.CLIENTNO, CLIENT.CNAME, PURCHASE.AMOUNT;
```

This only displays the results of all candidates. How would I start since i'm not looking for the max value of an amount but the total sum of the highest paying client?

Just going to put this as an additional question if someone could answer.. How would I change a constraint on one of my tables to be limited to a set of strings? Right now it is varchar2(25) but I want it to be only valid for like "string" "string2" help is appreciated.

Comment: This is close to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636487/inception-situation-with-oracle-sub-query-stuffs/16636781#16636781)

Comment: my bad didn't get the definition of `one that has purchased the most (total purchase amount) among all the company's clients, not just a the max amount in 1 purchase.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select CLIENTNO, CNAME
from (SELECT CLIENT.CLIENTNO, CLIENT.CNAME, rank() over (order by sum(PURCHASE.AMOUNT) desc) rnk
FROM PURCHASE join CLIENT on PURCHASE.CLIENTNO = CLIENT.CLIENTNO
GROUP BY CLIENT.CLIENTNO, CLIENT.CNAME)
where rnk = 1;
```

---

**UPDATE** If you want the sum of purchase amount

```
select CLIENTNO, CNAME, spa PURCHASE_AMOUNT
from (SELECT CLIENT.CLIENTNO, CLIENT.CNAME, sum(PURCHASE.AMOUNT) spa,  rank() over (order by sum(PURCHASE.AMOUNT) desc) rnk
FROM PURCHASE join CLIENT on PURCHASE.CLIENTNO = CLIENT.CLIENTNO
GROUP BY CLIENT.CLIENTNO, CLIENT.CNAME)
where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Hey A.B, sorry for the late response. Is it possible to show the PURCHASE.AMOUNT for the highest paying client?

Comment: @user1803009, I assume that you mean the total of his purchases amounts. See my update

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 Select c.ClientNo, c.CName Name, Sum(p.Amount)
 From Client c Join Purchase p 
    On p.clientNo = c.clientNo
 Group By c.CLientNo, c.ClientName
 Having Sum(p.Amount) =
       (Select Max(SumAmt)
        From (Select Sum(Amount) SumAmt
              From Purchase 
              Group By clientNo) z)
```

This sql says

"Select the clientNo, Name and sum of purchase amounts for the specific client whose sum of purchase amounts is the greatest."

```
 Select c.ClientNo, c.CName Name, Sum(p.Amount) -- Select the clientNo, Name and sum 
 From Client c Join Purchase p 
    On p.clientNo = c.clientNo
 Group By c.CLientNo, c.ClientName              -- for the specific client whose 
 Having Sum(p.Amount) =                         -- sum of purchase amounts is 
       (Select Max(SumAmt)                      -- Largest 
        From (Select Sum(Amount) SumAmt         -- Sum of purchase amounts
              From Purchase 
              Group By clientNo) z)             -- for each client
```

Comment: i am not getting the `having` clause logic. Could you help me? I mean to say why you took `z`?

Comment: the z is a quirk in how subqueries work.  They have to have an Alias, to be usable in the rest of the query.  the z is actually written  `...clientNo) As z)`  but the `As` is optional and can be omitted.

Comment: `Having` clauses are the same as a `Where` clause, except that while a `Where` clause expression filters the data from the processed results as they are BEFORE any aggregation,  the predicate expressions in a `Having` clause filters the results AFTER aggregation.